# The isset($_POST()) is returning false in the form

Tags: php, database, forms, isset

I've been trying to insert data into a database from the data i collected from a form.I used $_POST(id) but it was giving an error saying undefined index.So i used isset function.It fixed undefined index issue but now the isset is returning false so it is always inserting the default value of variable $a(ie 'n').
Heres the html file:

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<form  action="test.php">
<input type='text' id='a'/>
<input type='submit' value='sub'/>
</form>
</html>
```

and heres test.php :

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "test";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$a="n";
if (isset($_POST['a']))
$a=$_POST['a'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO test 
VALUES ('$a')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>                             

                                                                                                                                       whats wrong?
```

Comment: ***Use brackets for your control structures***. This is what happens when you omit them.

Comment: nope same issue with brackets

Comment: You're not providing your fields with valid names... thus the empty $_POST issues.

Answer (score 1):

Also add the method attribute to your form. By default it is `get`. As well as the name attribute to your input tag

```
<form action='test.php' method='post'>

<input type='text' name='a' id='a' />

<input type='submit' value='sub'/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply your fields with names, as it stands, these are not valid. As others have stated, you'll also need to ensure a method is set. The following is an example

```
<form  action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type='text' id='a' name='input_a'>
    <input type='submit' value='sub'/>
</form>
```

Then in your output of `$_POST` should show your incoming information.

Comment: If you don't set method='post' you'll still come away empty handed

Comment: wait just started to work ...the method='post' and name='input_a' did the trick.Thanks!

Comment: Great, if an answer has helped you out and solved your problem, feel free to mark it as a valid answer :)